# How to launch javascript counter with calculations when my text is in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter, viewport

I have a page with a counter that adds 8 to a quantity every day, in addition to that I need to make a countdown from zero. I have resolved those but the problem is that counter launches at page load and not when the text is on viewport. How can I solve that? I have found some functions but I'm not able to implement them :( This is my code which is inside an html block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p class="Count" id="uno"></p>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
</script>

<script>
var startDate1 = new Date(1522645200000)
var today1 = new Date();
var diff1 = Math.floor((today1 - startDate1)/(86400000))
var answer1 = 5600 + diff1 * 8

document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML = answer1;


$('.Count').each(function () {
 var $this = $(this);
 jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
   duration: 1000,
   easing: 'swing',
   step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jiquvud/3/edit?html,output) where you can see the code in execution.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/MvQKQg

Answer (score 0):

here goes the code to check whether the title is in ViewPort

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   var inViewPortBol = inViewPort();
   //if true means, you element invieport, the call you counterAnimation
});
function inViewPort() {
        var arentLocal = yourTitleElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        return parentLocal.bottom > 0 &&
            parentLocal.right > 0 &&
            parentLocal.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
            parentLocal.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}
```

let me know whether it helped.
Thanks!